# Extend AnchorTagHelper with automatic attribute in ASP Net.Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I try extend the built-in AnchorTagHelper object to add culture related settings to the generated url automatically.

My code:

```
namespace MyCoreSite.Mvc.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("a")]
    public class MyAnchorTagHelper : AnchorTagHelper
    {
        public MyAnchorTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
        {
        }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var requestCulture = this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();

            if (context.AllAttributes["asp-route-culture"] == null)
            {
                this.RouteValues.Add("culture", requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name);
            }

            base.Process(context, output);
            output.TagName = "a";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I use the default 'a' tag name in [HtmlTargetElement("a")] attribute it throws this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot override the 'href'
>   attribute for . An  with a specified 'href' must not have
>   attributes starting with 'asp-route-' or an 'asp-action',
>   'asp-controller', 'asp-area', 'asp-route', 'asp-protocol', 'asp-host',
>   'asp-fragment', 'asp-page' or 'asp-page-handler' attribute.'

If I use another tag name instead of 'a' (for example 'aa') its working, but I would like use 'a' tag in my views.

Please help me fix this problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can inherit from default `AnchorTagHelper`, override the `Process` method and then remove the original `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper` in `_ViewImports.cshtml` file. Using this method you will only have one `AnchorTagHelper` in your page.

Example `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@addTagHelper *, YourProject.PlatformExtensions
```

Example inherited `AnchorTagHelper`:

```
namespace YourProject.PlatformExtensions.TagHelpers
{
    public static class AnchorTagHelperSettings
    {
        public static string DefaultCulture = "en";
    }

    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ActionAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ControllerAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = AreaAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = PageAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = PageHandlerAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = FragmentAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = HostAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ProtocolAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteValuesDictionaryName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteValuesPrefix + "*")]
    public class AnchorTagHelper : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper
    {
        private const string ActionAttributeName = "asp-action";
        private const string ControllerAttributeName = "asp-controller";
        private const string AreaAttributeName = "asp-area";
        private const string PageAttributeName = "asp-page";
        private const string PageHandlerAttributeName = "asp-page-handler";
        private const string FragmentAttributeName = "asp-fragment";
        private const string HostAttributeName = "asp-host";
        private const string ProtocolAttributeName = "asp-protocol";
        private const string RouteAttributeName = "asp-route";
        private const string RouteValuesDictionaryName = "asp-all-route-data";
        private const string RouteValuesPrefix = "asp-route-";
        private const string Href = "href"; public override int Order => base.Order;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new <see cref="AnchorTagHelper"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generator">The <see cref="IHtmlGenerator"/>.</param>
        public AnchorTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
        {
        }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (!output.Attributes.ContainsName(Href) &&
                !context.AllAttributes.ContainsName("asp-route-lang") &&
                !(RouteValues?.ContainsKey("lang") == true))
            {
                var routeValues = ViewContext?.RouteData?.Values;

                if (routeValues != null)
                {
                    var langValue = routeValues["lang"]?.ToString();

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(langValue))
                    {
                        langValue = AnchorTagHelperSettings.DefaultCulture;
                    }

                    if (RouteValues == null)
                    {
                        RouteValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    }

                    RouteValues.Add("lang", langValue);
                }
            }

            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This code will be good I think, only problem, that I cannot override the <a> tag output. When I add for example output.Attributes.Add("asp-route-culture", requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name); nothing happens in rendered view. I would like see <a href="#" asp-route-culture="en-us"></a> in result, but I see the original <a href="#"></a> only. I debug my code and the output.Attributes.Add line executing well, but the modification not appear in the view.

Comment: Please note that in my code I am using `asp-route-lang` attribute, not `asp-route-culture`. Have you tried using  `asp-route-lang` attribute? This is just a sample and to make it work, you should also have `routeValues` populated. Sorry, I wrote this piece a few month ago and don't remember all details ;)

Answer (score 4):

Each tag helper runs independently in order, so you can't really override a default tag helper like `AnchorTagHelper` unless you remove the tag helper library entirely (remove the line that brings it in in `_ViewImports.cshtml`). Otherwise, what's actually happening here is that the default `AchorTagHelper` processes the tag, and then your custom `MyAnchorTagHelper` is processing the already modified tag. Inheriting from built-in tag helpers can actually cause problems if they're depending on a particular attribute being present before that isn't after.

For your particular scenario here, your best bet is to not inherit from `AnchorTagHelper` and instead, just modify the `href` attribute that will have been generated from `AnchorTagHelper` processing the tag first. Just make sure your tag helper library is included after the default in `_ViewImports.cshtml`, since order of ops will matter.

Comment: This means, that I need create my own href generation process instead of inherit the class form AnchorTagHelper? I can copy the content of AnchorTagHelper.cs from Github and extend it, but it's hard to keep updated in this case. If the original scenario not working, probably is better for me to find an another tag name instead of 'a'. For exampl 'url' as: [HtmlTargetElement("url")]